# PFSense new network, NAT and Firewalling

Tags: firewall, nat, pfsense

We have a PFSENSE installation with a few physical interfaces defined:

```
192.168.1.0/24 - LAN
192.168.2.0/24 - WIFI
192.168.3.0/24 - SERVERS
10.61.88.0/23 - New Requirement..... read on
```

The new requirement has been laid out by a supplier, they require access to their equipment, which is all attached to a DrayTek Router/Firewall.  The WAN interface of the Draytek is attached to the 10.61.88.254 interface in the PFSENSE machine, via a dedicated switch.

DHCP tells me the Draytek has pulled the 10.61.88.1 address which I reserved for it.  But the NAT rule for https and http doesn't work (they work fine on the other networks).  Am I missing something fundlemental?

Anyone got any ideas on troubleshooting the issue?

Comment: picture of PFsense FW rules for the new network and picture of you nat rules would help

Comment: I THINK I need to switch the New Requirement interface 'DIGI' to bridging mode, so it gives the external static IP to the Draytek router attached to the PFSENSE Interface.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

My approach was wrong, I setup the interface to bridge, works great.. [PFSENSE Bridge on of the Network Interfaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/362567/pfsense-bridge-on-of-the-network-interfaces)