# PFSENSE Bridge on of the Network Interfaces

Tags: routing, pfsense

I have a PFSENSE installation, which I have just added a new physical interface to for a new requirement 'DIGI'.  A third party has installed a DrayTek router on our network which has their equipment behind.  They require external access to the Draytek.

Can I bridge the new Interface I have just installed and then apply the external IP to the Draytek and if so how do I go about doing it?

The images attached are my guess approaches to doing it..

[image: Bridges]
[image: Interfaces]

Comment: Am I getting you right:
pfSense connects to the WAN and has ext. IP like 1.2.3.4. DrayTek sits behind pfSense and they need to access it from WAN over 1.2.3.4 on some ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:1 NAT solved this problem....

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer. And to help others, perhaps you could elaborate on the steps you took to solve the problem.